# Open Facebook URL in Facebook App

Tags: ios, applications, facebook

I know using the `fb://URL` scheme I can open certain links in the Native Facebook App,

e.g. `fb://page/137947732957611` will open the Apple Facebook page.

Is there anyway I can open pages without knowing the pageid though, eg so I can just open https://www.facebook.com/Google but within the Facebook App?

Comment: I assume you've tried "fb://page/Google" and similar?

Comment: Yes fb://page/104958162837 loads Google as expected and fb://page/google shows an error

Answer (score 1):

### No it's not possible!

The reason is that the Facebook url scheme needs a unique ID for open a certain page and if you look the screenshot below you can see that the "Google" is Name and Username.

[image]